# Force wireless adapter to connect 802.11n?

Tags: windows-10, wireless-networking, 802.11n

I have an Xiaomi 802.11n USB Wireless Adapter and a TP-Link WR740N wireless Router, the adapter is always connected using 802.11g and the speed of the connection is 54Mps.

Can I force my pc to connect using 802.11n protocol?

I know that I can limit clients with 802.11n to connect to the router from the router side, but I don't want to change other client settings.

Here is a screen shot of my network adapter settings:

[image]

Comment: You can also change your PC setting to only connect to 802.11n and ignore everything else. And you will need to provide what OS your PC is running so we can help you better. I know for sure on Windows OS you can change the WiFi Adapter settings to do exactly that. If it is a different OS - I won't have the answer handy.

Comment: How many 802.11g clients do you have other than the adapter in question?

Comment: At least 5 other wireless clients are connected to the same router via 802.11n protocol, and only my pc on g protocol